# Normal distribution of a constant value

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to apply a normal distribution with python to a constant value to obtain an histogram like the image given below. The sum of the histogram should be the input value.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to specify a little bit more than just the sum of the values. How many of those bars do you need (in the picture there seem to be 17 bars)? What is the range of values (minimim and maximum in the in the x-axis of the picture)?

Comment: I would like to obtain an arbitrary number of bars and the same for the range of values  that it hould be positive

Comment: The continuous version of this is of course this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
When you have the range, you can specify $\mu$ and $\sigma$. And for the "input value", notice that if you have the Gauss curve as $\varphi(x)$ then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(x)\, dx = 1
$$
meaning that the "sum" of the values is 1. So you just need to multiply the result by the "input value". So now you have the continuous version, then the next step is to generate the histogram version ...